# Search Items in The ListBox In Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, mvvm, listbox

I want to search the name in the list box. I am using MVVM pattern in my application.

My Xaml coding for Listbox

```
 <ListBox  Height="440" Background="Azure" ItemsSource="{Binding Content,Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,230,0,0" Name="OutGoingInvitationList" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="468" BorderBrush="#00565353" SelectionChanged="listBox1_SelectionChanged">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Name="ListPersonImage" Source="{Binding ListImage}" Height="100" Width="100" Stretch="Uniform" Margin="10,2,0,0" ImageFailed="Image_ImageFailed" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ListFullName}" Name="ListPersonFullName" Width="200" Foreground="Black" Margin="10,10,0,0" FontWeight="SemiBold" FontSize="22" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ListBio}" Name="ListPersonBio" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Foreground="Black" Margin="-200,50,0,0" FontWeight="ExtraLight" FontSize="20" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

Here Content have all the list values. 
Now it shows the result. Now i want search the person name. I want to write the code in

```
private void OnTextBoxTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
      {
      }
```

Is it possible to search the names in the listbox. Here i want only show the items in Listbox searched items only. Sorry for the poor English.

Please tell me how to perform this action.

Thanks in advance..

My View Model:

```
 invitationsButton = new ReactiveAsyncCommand();

        var invitationResults = invitationsButton.RegisterAsyncObservable(_ =>
        {
            return HTTPServices.postAndGetResponse((new PersonSearchOperation().GetInvitations(ServiceConstants.Identity_Number)));
        });

        invitationResults.Subscribe(
         x =>
         {

             ServiceModel sm = new ServiceModel();
             Content = new List<ListContactsModel>();
             Content1 = new List<ListContactsModel>();
             ServiceConstants.Temp_Response = x;
             List<ListContactsModel> result = ListContactsModel.extract(x, sm, OutGoingInvitation);

             if (!((string.IsNullOrEmpty(sm.NetErrorCode)) && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sm.ProvResErrCode))))
             {
                 string errCode = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(sm.NetErrorCode) ? sm.NetErrorCode : sm.ProvResErrCode;
                 string errDesc = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(sm.NetErrorDesc) ? sm.NetErrorDesc : sm.ProvResErrDesc;
                 MessageBox.Show(errCode + "/" + errDesc);
             }
             else if (result.Count > 0)
             {
                 Content.AddRange(result);//Outgoing Invitations

             }
             else
             {
                 MessageBox.Show("There is No Invitations For You"); //Use Resource Bundle
             }
         }
        );
```

Now Content have all the result. 
Please tell me now where i have to implement Search operation?
Actually i have no idea where i have to write the Search Operation Code??

In My view Model I have add this code. I can see the output in Console Window. But UI is not  updating.

```
 public void SearchMethod(String searchValue)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("searchValue...." + searchValue);
        Console.WriteLine("ServiceConstants.Temp_Response ...." + ServiceConstants.Temp_Response);
        AppGlobalConstants.Temp_SearchValue = searchValue;
        ServiceModel sm = new ServiceModel();
        Content = new List<ListContactsModel>();
        List<ListContactsModel> result = ListContactsModel.extract(ServiceConstants.Temp_Response, sm, OutGoingInvitation);

        if (!((string.IsNullOrEmpty(sm.NetErrorCode)) && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sm.ProvResErrCode))))
        {
            string errCode = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(sm.NetErrorCode) ? sm.NetErrorCode : sm.ProvResErrCode;
            string errDesc = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(sm.NetErrorDesc) ? sm.NetErrorDesc : sm.ProvResErrDesc;
            MessageBox.Show(errCode + "/" + errDesc);
        }
        else if (result.Count > 0)
        {

            Content.AddRange(result);
            Console.WriteLine("Content.Count==>>" + Content.Count);
        }

    }
```

In My CS file

```
   private void OnTextBoxTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {

            listContactsViewModel.SearchMethod(userIDTextBox.Text);
    }
```

Sorry. I am very new to windows phone application development. In fact this is my very first project. That's why i don't have any idea. Please tell me where i have to make changes??

Answer (score 0):

In your ViewModel you should have a private collection to hold the orignal list while you can set the search result in content.

In your viewmodel

```
private List<YourClass> orignalList;

public void Search(string query)
{
    // do your query
    List<YourClass> list = get...;

    // clear content
    Content.Clear();

    foreach(var item in list)
    {
       Content.Add(item)
    }
 }
```

If you clear the query, you use the orignalList to fill Content.

Remember to set Content as `ObservableCollection`

Comment: Hi AlexisXu.. Thanks for your reply.. I have add my view model code. Please refer that i am i right or wrong?

Comment: Thanks.. But still i have not get idea. Please refer my coding. I have add some more code.